# The tangent to the curve $y=x-x^3$ at point P meets the curve again at point Q.

Tags: coordinate-systems, curves, tangent-line

One point of trisection lies on $y$ axis. What is the equation of locus of other point of trisection?

I have tried finding the slope, distance and tangent equation but ended up with no results and a tedious work. Can someone help me in giving an insight to this problem and its solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(p,p-p^3)$. Since $y'=1-3x^2$, the equation of the tangent line at $P$ is given by
$$y-(p-p^3)=(1-3p^2)(x-p)$$
We want to find $x\not=p$ such that
$$(x-x^3)-(p-p^3)=(1-3p^2)(x-p),$$
i.e.
$$x^3-3p^2x+2p^3=0$$
Since the LHS is divisible by $(x-p)^2$, we obtain
$$(x-p)^2(x+2p)=0.$$
Hence, $Q(-2p, 8p^3-2p)$. I think that you can continue from here.

---

For the trisection points $R_1,R_2$ of the line segment $PQ$ :

$R_1(x_1,y_1)$ : $$x_1=\frac{2\times p+1\times (-2p)}{3}=0,\quad y_1=\frac{2\times (p-p^3)+1\times (8p^3-2p)}{3}$$

$R_2(x_2,y_2)$ : $$x_2=\frac{1\times p+2\times (-2p)}{3},\quad y_2=\frac{1\times (p-p^3)+2\times (8p^3-2p)}{3}$$

Comment: Am sorry... But I am not able to proceed

Comment: @HaniMohammed: Set $Q(X,Y)$. Then, you have $X=-2p$, i.e. $p=-X/2$. Now use that $Y=8p^3-2p$ to eliminate $p$.

Comment: But I want the locus of the other point of intersection. Not of Q

Comment: @HaniMohammed: I see what you mean. see the addition in my answer.

Comment: @HaniMohammed: So, I think that you are interested in $R_2$ in my answer since $R_1$ is on $y$-axis.

Comment: Yes yes..... Thanx a lot for your time... Sorry that I can't vote yet

Comment: @HaniMohammed: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Given $y=x-x^3$ and a tangent at point $P(a,a-a^3)$ also intersects the graph at a point $Q$.

The slope of the tangent line is $y=1-3x^2$, so the slope of the tangent line at $(a,a-a^3)$ on the graph is $m=1-3a^2$.

So the equation of the tangent line at that point is

\begin{equation}
y-a+a^3=(1-3a^2)(x-a)
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
y=(1-3a^2)x+2a^3
\end{equation}

Since $Q$ lies on the tangent line and also on the curve, the $x$ coordinate of $Q$ satisfies the equation

\begin{equation}
x-x^3=(1-3a^2)x+2a^3
\end{equation}

which can be re-written

\begin{equation}
x^3-3a^2x+2a^3=0
\end{equation}

Since $P$ also lies on the tangent line and the curve we know that $x=a$ is one solution of this equation. Thus we may factor out $x-a$ to obtain the equation

\begin{equation}
(x-a)(x^2+ax-2a^2)=0
\end{equation}

and the quadratic can also be factored to give

\begin{equation}
(x-a)^2(x+2a)=0
\end{equation}

We should not be surprised to see that $a$ is a double solution since that is where the tangent it. But the tangent line crosses the graph at $x=-2a$ so that is a single root of the polynomial.

The coordinates of $Q$ are $(-2a,-2a+8a^3)$.

Comment: I see that @mathlove types much faster than I.

Comment: How to find locus of the other point of trisection?

Comment: I assumed that by "trisection" you meant "intersection" and that by "locus" you meant "location", that is, the coordinates.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: trisection of the line segment $PQ$, maybe?

Comment: By trisection I meant two points that divide the line into 3 equal parts. One of the point is given. What is the locus ,that is ,equation of all possible values of the other point.

Comment: The point one-third of the way from $P$ to $Q$ is $ T_1=\frac{2}{3}P+\frac{1}{3}Q$ and the point two-thirds of the way from $P$ to $Q$ is $T_2=\frac{1}{3}P+\frac{2}{3}Q$. So,  $T_1=(0,2a^3)$ and $T_2=(-a,-a+5a^3)$